# Site for computer networking project ideas

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site where I can ask questions about computer networking project ideas?

Comment: Probably not. What kind of ideas do you mean?

Comment: @Jesi computer networking project idea could mean 9000 different things... please provide more detail...

Comment: Idea may be on network security, wireless network, Network performance. You can also give me any other links those are not Stack Exchange account.

Comment: Uuhhh...yeah, we have at least six different sites where you can ask those questions, Server Fault and Security f.e..

Comment: Be more specific, but I have a feeling 99% of any related questions would fall under Serverfault, Security, StackOverflow, SuperUser or Webmasters or Database Administrators, depending on what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 8):

There generally aren't any Stack Exchange communities which serve to help people develop their ideas.  (Though I could be wrong, there are more and more sites being created these days.)

Stack Exchange's question and answer format is geared more toward the implementation, not the idea.  There are certainly a number of less concrete questions on Stack Overflow, and even more on Programmers, but the focus remains pretty clear.  These sites are about solving discrete problems, not discussing ideas.

For example, if your question was:

> I have an idea for a computer network project.  It's for creating a way to connect computers together in a peer-to-peer manner instead of through a server.  It'll be like the next Facebook, but for computers!  Can anybody tell me where to get started?

Then your question would be closed.  It doesn't belong on any Stack Exchange site (that I know of).

However, if your questions was:

> I've been implementing this network project, and I'm stuck on something.  I'm trying to accomplish [add details here] and I started by [add details here].  However, when I get to the point that I need to [add details here] I can't seem to get around [add details about an observed problem here].  I thought I'd be able to [add details here], but [add details here] is getting in the way.  Does anybody have any insight on this?  Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?

Then your question would be a better fit.

Notice the main difference is in the amount of work you put into the question.  Open-ended discussions don't make for good questions on Stack Exchange.  But discrete reproducible problems with specific parameters make for great questions.

A few things that should go into any given question in most cases:

1. What you're trying to accomplish.
2. *Why* you're trying to accomplish it (maybe the answer requires taking a step back and approaching the overall goal differently).
3. How you're trying to accomplish it.
4. A problem you've encountered.
5. How you've attempted to diagnose the problem (information from your debugger, steps taken to test it, etc.).
6. Expected behavior vs. observed behavior.

You can see where this is going.  The more details you present, the more help can be provided.  It's especially helpful to give a complete example to reproduce the issue.  For example, with code, don't just post all of your code.  Remove anything unrelated to the problem.  Reproduce the problem with as little code as possible.  (In most cases this process will reveal the answer to you before you even post the question.)

This isn't to say more open-ended and subjective Stack Exchange sites don't exist.  The English Language and Usage site, the Parenting site, etc. are all much more subjective in the questions and answers they accept.  So, for any given site, you'll definitely want to check the FAQ and browse some example questions before proceeding.  But for the technical sites (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, etc.) the format is generally much more concrete.

Comment: +1 a question about a "networking project idea" leads me to believe that the user is looking for subjective opinions, and therefore is off topic everywhere.  If the user has specific, answerable questions about technical aspects of the hypothetical project, then it might be on topic.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is vague, but I'll try and point you in the right direction.

[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour) is probably the first place you should look, you might want to check out [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) also.

If you mean network programming, I would look at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

If you're looking into networking because of a game (like Minecraft networking or something like that...), check out [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour).

You asked for a website that didn't need to be from Stack Exchange, so [here is an amazing tutorial on networking](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/networking/guide/).

Comment: Tnanx for your answer. I actually want some project ideas like configuring "automatic routing protocol" is a project. you can give me  any links where can I get such project idea.

Comment: @Jesi Then check out http://serverfault.com/ you can probably get more information there

Comment: @Jesi what do you mean by "ideas" exactly?

Comment: I asked in serverfault but they said me that this is not proper place for project idea. They generally solve networking problem but do not provide any project idea.

Comment: Actually I have to do a project for the course "Data Communication and Networking".

Comment: @Jesi You never ask for ideas, you ask for solutions to problems. You'll need to come up with the idea yourself...